# Coremltools converting CNN + LSTM issues

Tags: python, ios, keras, coremltools

I've trained a model in keras using the following structure.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Convolution2D(16, 3, 3, border_mode="same", activation='relu'), input_shape=(None, image_height, image_width, 3)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation='relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten(), name='out1'))
model.add(LSTM(256, name='lstm'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='out'))
```

The model works great, but I need to convert it to CoreML. When I attempt that I get the following error.

```
0 : time_distributed_1_input, <keras.engine.topology.InputLayer object at 0x7f05c8711390>
1 : time_distributed_1, <keras.layers.wrappers.TimeDistributed object at 0x7f05c8711450>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "converter.py", line 92, in <module>
    coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert(loaded_model, input_names=["image"], output_names=["out1"])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/coremltools/converters/keras/_keras_converter.py", line 752, in convert
    custom_conversion_functions=custom_conversion_functions)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/coremltools/converters/keras/_keras_converter.py", line 550, in convertToSpec
    custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/coremltools/converters/keras/_keras2_converter.py", line 311, in _convert
    converter_func(builder, layer, input_names, output_names, keras_layer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/coremltools/converters/keras/_layers2.py", line 284, in convert_convolution
    output_blob_shape = list(filter(None, keras_layer.output_shape))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 1062, in output_shape
    raise AttributeError('The layer has never been called '
AttributeError: The layer has never been called and thus has no defined output shape.
```

Any ideas on how I can get this working in iOS. Is there a work around with coremltools that I could do to get this working?

Comment: I Also have the same problem with keras 2.2.0 with tensoeflow backend 1.9. Did you resolved the issue? I will appreciate it if you share.

Comment: I did. I had to split the inputs, run them separately through cnn, concatenate the feature vectors then run that through the LSTM.

Comment: Do you concatenate using for loop? (I mean do you concatenate the features (output of all frames from cnn) ? can you please explain it.
I am converting cnn and lstm separately for now. I prefer to make only one coreML - thankyou

Comment: Yes, I don't have the exact code to share, but you use a for loop creating n number of input tensors that you need. Append the output features of each input to an array then use a concatenate keras layer. Reshape the concatenate layer if you need – to (n, feature_size) then pass it into the lstm.